# using structure as a value for containers.Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I am trying to add a structure as a value for `container.Map`, for example I'm trying to add `segments` strcuture to `cont` container.

Code:

```
classdef datHandle < handle
    properties           
       cont = containers.Map('KeyType','int32','ValueType','any');
    end

    methods
        function this = addsignal(this, varargin)

            interval = diff(varargin{2});

            [~, locations] = findpeaks(interval,'THRESHOLD',0.7);

            edges = [0; locations; numel(varargin{1})+1];  %note that 0 and one past the end is on purpose
            newsegments = struct('signal', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1), 'time', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1));
            %this loop works for no peaks, 1 peak and more than one peak (because of the 0 and numel+1)
            for edgeidx = 1 : numel(edges) - 1
                newsegments(edgeidx).signal = varargin{1}((edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1));
                newsegments(edgeidx).time = varargin{2}(edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1);

            end
            global p
            if length(this.map) == 0
                p = 2;
                this.cont(1) = newsegments;
            else
                this.cont(p) = newsegments;
                p = p+1;
            end


        end
    end
end
```

Is this even possible, It adds fine, but when i try to retrieve the values.

`cont.values(1)`
I am getting:

`Error using containers.Map/values
Parameter must be 'cell'.`

edit1:

```html
matlab Script file:

filename1 = import('file1')
singal1 = filename1.yaxis
time1 = filename1.xaxis
filename2 = import('file2')
signal2 = filename2.yaxis
time2 = filename2.yaxis

f = ltiFilter.dathandle();

f.addsignal(signal1,time1)
f.addsignal(signal2,time2)
```

Comment: First of all create a [Minimal Working Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code is not valid Matlab code. Second, you define `cont`, but in the function you use `this.map`. Lastly, `cont.values`returns a cell array. Use `cont(1)` to get the stored value.

Comment: Thank you, i just edited the code. so when i do `cont(1)`, it returns a `3x1` struct array with 3 fields, is there any when i can add a field to this struct without creating more struct?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to achieve. In the above code, `this.segments` points to the same struct every time. Do you want different structs for each segment or just an array structs? Maybe you don't need the map?

Comment: I have edited my code properly, now hopefully you will understand the code.

Comment: now the `newsegments`struct has 2 fields. not the `cont(1)` returns a `3x1` struct with 2 fields, can i add more fields to this `3x1` struct in another part of my program

Comment: I still don't understand the need for a for using `containers.Map`, when all you do is increment the key. Use an [array of structs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html) for that.Further, could you provide some example input data.

Comment: @Jørgen, I previously had array of structure, What i actually am doing is `addsignal` function takes a big signal, chops it into multiple small signals `newsegments`, i used to store all these segments in a array of structure. but the function `addsignal` will be called multiple times with diff signals. and i had no way of saying which segment belongs to which signal. with `container.map` i can clearly say `cont(1)` belongs to 1st signal, `cont(2)` belong to 2nd signal and so on.

Comment: @Jørgen, check my edit1. it'll show an example of how this is called.

Comment: so `this.cont(1)` has `3x1`array with 3 fields, i am trying to add a new field, say `new`. `this.cont(1).new = []`. this returns a error saying `Only one level of indexing is supported by a containers.Map.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
classdef datHandle < handle
    properties
        segments = {};
    end

    methods
        function this = addsignal(this, varargin)

            interval = diff(varargin{2});

            [~, locations] = findpeaks(interval,'THRESHOLD',0.7);

            %note that 0 and one past the end is on purpose
            edges = [0; locations; numel(varargin{1})+1];  
            newsegments = struct('signal', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1), 'time', cell(numel(edges)-1, 1));

            %this loop works for no peaks, 1 peak and more than one peak (because of the 0 and numel+1)
           for edgeidx = 1 : numel(edges) - 1
               newsegments(edgeidx).signal = varargin{1}((edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1));
               newsegments(edgeidx).time = varargin{2}(edges(edgeidx)+1 : edges(edgeidx+1)-1);

         end

         this.segments{end+1} = newsegments;
         end
     end
end
```

Here is an example of how it works. The segments are stored in an cell array.

```
>> d = datHandle;
>> d.addsignal([0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0], [0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0] )

ans = 

  datHandle with properties:

    segments: {[2x1 struct]}

>> d.addsignal([0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0], [0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0] )

ans = 

  datHandle with properties:

    segments: {[2x1 struct]  [2x1 struct]}

>> d.segments{1}

ans = 

2x1 struct array with fields:

    signal
    time

>> d.segments{2}(1)

ans = 

    signal: [0 0 0]
      time: [0 0 0]
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for!. if i want to add an extra field. Should i just do `d.segments{2}(1).newfield = []`

Comment: Yes no problem with that. Note that the extra field will be added to all structs in `segments`

Comment: Thanks helped alot!